# Pantheon desktop and ubuntu questions

Tags: 18.04, elementary, pantheon

Hi everyone im kind of new to linux and I have the latest version of ubuntu installed. I wanted to try the pantheon desktop of elementary os so I installed it through the terminal but I thought that as usual it would just add the option at the loggin screen of pantheon desktop along side the regular ubuntu but it also changed the backround of the ubuntu desktop to a wallpaper of 5.0 "JUNO" BETA, what happened here? did I modify my default ubuntu? I just wanted to add the pantheon desktop option at the login screen without changing ubuntu.

edit: since I did that the ctrl+alt+T command to open the terminal doesnt work

Comment: If you want to "try" things, use a Live USB or use virtualization or install in a new partition.

Comment: ok I will from now on. But why installing the lxde desktop didnt cause any of this?

Comment: Some desktop environments such as lxde (and even xfce) don't cause issues when added but others do!